# Pipelines buffer preserving until processing is complete

Tags: c#, system.threading.channels, system.io.pipelines

I am researching the possibility of using pipelines for processing binary messages coming from network.
The binary messages i will be processing come with an payload and it is desirable to keep the payload in its binary form.

The idea is to read out the whole message and create a slice of message and its payload, once the message is completely read it will be passed to a channel chain for processing, the processing will not be instant and might take some time or be executed later and the goal is **not to have the pipe reader wait** until the processing is complete, then once the message processing is complete i would need to release the processed buffer region to the pipe writer.

Now of course i could just create a new byte array and copy the data coming from pipe writer but that would beat the purpose of no-copy? So as i understand i would need some buffer synchronization between the pipeline and the channel?
I observed the available apis (**AdvanceTo**) of pipe reader where its possible to tell the pipe reader what was consumed and what was examined but cant get around how this could be synced outside of the pipe reading method.

So the question would be whether there are some techniques or examples on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer obtained from `TryRead`/`ReadAsync` is only valid until you call `AdvanceTo`, with the *expectation* that as soon as you've done that: anything you reported as consumed is available to be recycled for use elsewhere (which could be parallel/concurrent readers). Strictly speaking: even the bits you *haven't* reported as consumed: you still shouldn't treat as valid once you've called `AdvanceTo` (although in reality, it is likely that they'll still be the same segments - just: that isn't the concern of the caller; to the caller, it is only valid between the read and the advance).

This means that you explicitly can't do:

```cs
while (...)
{
    var result = await pipe.ReadAsync();
    if (TryIdentifyFrameBoundary(out var frame)) {
        BeginProcessingInBackground(frame); // <==== THIS IS A PROBLEM!
        reader.AdvanceTo(frame.End, frame.End);
    }
    else if { // take nothing
        reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);
        if (result.IsCompleted) break; // that's all folks
    }
}
```

because the "in background" bit, when it fires, could now be reading someone else's data (due to it being reused already).

So: *either* you need to process the frame contents as part of the read loop, *or* you're going to have to make a copy of the data, most likely by using:

```
c#
var len = checked ((int)buffer.Length);
var oversized = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(len);
buffer.CopyTo(oversized);
```

and pass `oversized` to your background processing, remembering to only look at the first `len` bytes of it. You *could* pass this as a `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`, but you need to consider that you're also going to want to return it to the array-pool afterwards (probably in a `finally` block), and passing it as a memory makes it a little more awkward (but not impossible, thanks to `MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray`).

---

Note: in early versions of the pipelines API, there was an element of reference-counting, which *did* allow you to preserve buffers, but it had a few problems:

- it complicated the API hugely
- it led to leaked buffers
- it was ambiguous and confusing what "preserved" meant; is the count until it gets *reused*? or *released completely*?

so that feature was dropped.

Comment: Got it, this would be the way i would go if no solutions was found. One question, since i will have some functions that will produce unknown/variable size buffer upon the call would the good practice be to have shared MemoryPool passed around in function parameters so the function could allocate required buffer? The function caller would be responsible of releasing the buffer once its processed. Is that a common approach ?

Comment: @NullReference honestly, unless there's a good reason, I'd just keep it simple and use the shared buffer pool (`ArrayPool<T>.Shared`)

Comment: Well yes it could be a shared one, i will examine if i have any good reasons for that :) As i understand the choice between ArrayPool and MemoryPool will depend on the underlying apis i will be using to parse/handle data?

Comment: @NullReference not really, in my opinion; you can trivially create a `[ReadOnly]Memory<T>` from a `T[]`, while fixing the "oversized" thing at the same time, and `MemoryPool<T>` has the overhead of an allocation for the `IDisposable`. Frankly, in most code there's very little reason to use `MemoryPoolT<T>` instead of just `ArrayPool<T>`. When it *does* get interesting is: when you want to use unmanaged memory for your pool.

Comment: Hi Marc, is it possible to call `await reader.ReadAsync();` repeatedly in a loop until `readResult.IsCompleted` turns true - and then read out the whole data just once? I am trying it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72562782/165071

Comment: @AlexanderFarber yes - replied in context